# How to pass float number as rake task argument?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, arguments, rake

How do i pass float number as an argument in rake task

```
desc "example rake"
task :to_store_number, [:number1, :number2] do |t, args|
  a = "#{args[:number1].to_f}" * "#{args[:number2].to_f}"
  puts a
end
```

Which gives error "TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Comment: Where was the error raised? Which line? You code works fine here.

Comment: @ArieShaw, I just gave sample code, `#{args[:number].class}` returns string, how to pass float number in rake not string?

Comment: You can't. Command line arguments are always passed in as `String`. You need to parse them to your desired format manually (`args[:number].to_f`).

Comment: @ArieShaw - Passing args[:number] not "#{args[:number]}", fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arguments like args[:number] and not as "#{args[:number]}" fixed it

```
desc "example rake"
task :to_store_number, [:number1, :number2] do |t, args|
  a = args[:number1].to_f * args[:number2].to_f
  puts a
end
```